# Проблема с заменой символов

Tags: python

Моя задача заключается в создании программы, которая принимает номер телефона формата +38(ХХХ)ХХХХХХХ 
Я должен обработать введенный пользователем номер, убрав из него + и (), то есть запринтить только 38ХХХХХХХХХХ

Не могу понять в чем проблема, все время пишет, что неверный формат, хоть при тесте ввожу +38(777)7777777

Вот код:

```
string = input('phone number')
if string.startswith ('()'):
    print(string.replace('()', ''))
else:
    len(string) > 15
    print ('only format +38(XXX)XXXXXXX')
```

Comment: Метод startswith возвращает флаг(True, False) о том, начинается ли строка с указанных вами символов.

Comment: `import re` и `re.sub(r'[\+\(\)]', '', string)`

Comment: @splash58, я бы использовал r’\D’ - все «не цифры» ;) Кстати, может оформите как ответ?

Comment: @maxU - логично. Буквы Х  смутили :)

Comment: `''.join(filter(str.isdigit, string))`

Comment: Югославские номера?! Ого!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
phone = '+38(777)7777777'
normalized = ''.join(c for c in phone if c.isdigit())
```

Comment: Можете написать в развернутом виде, что значит " с ", используя мой код .

Comment: `c` - это символ строки `phone`. Генераторное выражение отфильтровывает все нецифровые символы, и полученная последовательность склеивается в результирующую строку.

Comment: Ничего не понял, можно готовый вариант ?

Comment: Это и есть готовый вариант. Можете его скопировать и запустить.

Comment: не работает . я скопировал и вставил - 0 эффекта , ничего в терминале нет.

Comment: А не пробовали переменную `normalized` вывести? https://ideone.com/IbJxdJ

Comment: Для строк прекрасно работает `map()`, зачем это извращение с `for`?

Comment: @0andriy для Python идиоматичными являются как раз _включения_. Использование `map` и `filter` Гвидо осуждает.

Comment: Гвидо давно не торт. Пусть осуждает дальше, но преимущество `map()` и `filter()` для строк очевидны.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_phone():
    string = input("Phone: ")
    normalized = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, string))
    if len(normalized) > 15:
        print ('only format +38(XXX)XXXXXXX')
        get_phone()
    else:
        print("Done!")
```